# ADB command to resume android app to foreground without knowing activity

Tags: android, adb, appium

I want to bring a background application to the foreground by its package name without knowing the current activity.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by calling `driver.activateApp(package-name);` see [this](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/app/activate-app/) for more details

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's possible to run application specifying **package name only** using **monkey** tool by follow this pattern:

```
adb shell monkey -p your.app.package.name -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

Command is used to run app using monkey tool which generates random input for application. The last part of command is **integer** which specify the number of generated random **input** for app. In this case the number is 1, which in fact is used to launch the app **(icon click)**.

**More simplify version of adb command:**

`android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` is default as it is part of `Andriod` OS. so You can simplify it

```
adb shell monkey -p your.app.package.name 1
```

Hope it will help you.